# Hash user emails in database?

Tags: database, users, security

I have a wordpress based website, a very important thing is that no one should get to know the email addresses of the people who will admin.

I will make the whole website private but I am still thinking what else could I do. So I got the idea I could hash the emails in the db.

Has anyone done that?

What are the functionalities that need email address? As far as I know it is only needed when creating the user, because the password is sent to the user, and then it is needed at a password reset. So I would need to modify these so that it decrypts the email first.

Is there anything else? Do you think it's useless as a security measure?

Comment: Just an alternative non-WordPress solution: You could setup postboxes, with general user names and from there, redirect the mails to the sensitive email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashing is a one-way function, meaning you can't get back an original string from a hash value.

You could use the PHP function `mcrypt_encrypt` to "encrypt" the email address and `mcrypt_decrypt` to convert it back.

If you went that route, you could hook into `password_reset` to decode the email address before the password reset is sent, and then hook into `password_reset_after` to encode it again after.